# R ggplot2 geom_col bars not aligned with x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to have a barplot with different gaps for bars in same group, here exampled codes.

```
df <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3),
  category = rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"), 3),
  value = rnorm(9)
)
df$width = ifelse(df$category=="X",2,1)

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = category)) +
  geom_col(width = df$width,position = position_dodge2(padding = c(0.5,0,0))) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

I got the gap thing done, but the bars are not aligned with x-axis, as showed.

[image: unexpected barplot]

How to fixed this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be your `df$width` variables. Try setting them so each category sums to 1:

```
set.seed(1) # Make the result reproducible

df <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3),
  category = rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"), 3),
  value = rnorm(9)
)

df$width = ifelse(df$category=="X",.5,.25) # This is what I changed

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = category)) +
  geom_col(width = df$width,
           position = position_dodge2(padding = c(0.5,0.5,0.5))) + # Also edited your padding variables
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

Result:
[image: result]

Comment: Yes, that works, the grouped bars are aligned correctly now, thank you! Although have no idea of reason. I guess there should be a internal ``width`` parameter defaulted to 1, so the sum of widths of all members in ``category`` should be 1? And I keep the ``padding`` unchanges as category X belongs to a level and category Y, Z belong to another (not shown in the example), I created the gap by ``padding`` to distinguish between different levels.

Comment: Yes. as far as I understand, the 'space' occupied by each categorical variable == 1. There may be a way to scale variables within each category to produce your desired result, but editing the width values seemed a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `preserve` argument inside the `position_dodge2()` function, is this what you want?

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = factor(category))) +
  geom_col(width = df$width,position = position_dodge2(padding = c(0.5,0,0),
                                                       preserve = 'single')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

Update per OP's comment, try removing your width argument.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = value, fill = factor(category))) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge2(padding = c(0.5,0,0),
                                                       preserve = 'single')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Very colse but looks like group C is still unaligned. And would you please show me how to expand the gaps between groups in this instance? Setting `width` in `position_dodge2` is not working.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean by "expand the gaps"? You are calling the `padding` argument, if you want to change this just change those values, for example `padding = c(0.5,0.5,0)` adds the same space between all columns. Check the update.